# How to know if a string is ended RegularExpresion javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings like this.

```
var myArray =["pr-1.sq-1.reply-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq-1.receive-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq-1.assign-1",  
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq",
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq.receive-1"
             ];
```

and I wish to go through the array element and return only the follwing:

```
returningArray = ["pr-1.sq-1.fw-1", "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq"];
```

notice: The value of the integer at the end of string is dynamic and can be any number [o-9].
this is my code:

```
var myRegex = /\b.fw[-*][(1-9)*][^a-z]\b/;
for(var i =0; i<myArray.length; i++){
   if(myRegex.test(myArray[i]){
      returningArray.push(myArray[i]);
   }
}
```

my big problem is at the level of `myRegex` because it will return every thing.

Comment: What is logic to get those 2 elements?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: please excuse me it just that my my data set is very large and i was trying to give a meaning to the question i am asking. i am working on a project dealing with JSplomb which is a js library that that gives possibility to connect html element and my array here is the set of ID's found in my HTML file. So, i am trying to get the suitable ID's according to my project.

Comment: Please can you reupvote my reputation ? i will be very clear the next time. Thanks

Comment: `o` is not a number. It's a small letter `O`, not zero `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only wanted to be specific to match **fw-1** or **fw-1.sq** I  assume your data set is going to be larger and more varied than what you have provided us so I have modified the regex to match **fw-[0-9]** and then look for end of string (which is denoted by a $ in regex) or **fw-1** followed by **.sq**. This rule looks like **($|.sq$)** which tells regexp to **match end of line immediately or .sq then end of line**.

```
var myArray =["pr-1.sq-1.reply-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq-1.receive-1", 
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq-1.assign-1",  
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq",
              "pr-1.sq-1.fw-1.sq.receive-1"
             ];
var returningArray = [];
var myRegex = /\.fw-([1-9])($|\.sq$)/;
for(var i =0; i<myArray.length; i++){
   if(myArray[i].match(myRegex)) {
      returningArray.push(myArray[i]);
   }
}

console.log(returningArray);
```

Comment: Thanks it solve my problem

Comment: sure, if it helped then you can help the site by marking it correct which will indicate that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this regex:

```
var myRegex = /.fw-[0-9](.\w{0,2})?$/;
```

`'?'` - all characters in brackets are optional, and `'$'` - matches end of string.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/3jhzzqva/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/^.+fw-[1-9]+(.[^.-]+)*$/ig
```